# How to open emacs from Mac's Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, emacs

On my Mac, I would like to be able to right-click on a file and  then select "open with.." emacs.

How can I accomplish that? (On my Mac, I have emacs in /usr/bin)

Comment: Is [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) not an option for you?

Comment: Yes, I have have downloaded it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the most recent version of [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) which is "standard" Emacs with a lot of essential OS X customization.

Answer (score 7):

You can also achieve the result you want with an actual terminal window and the command-line `emacs`. To do that, open *Automator.app* from your applications folder, and create a new *Application*.

Here, from the left, drag *Run AppleScript* to the right, and paste the following:

```
on run {input}
    set filepath to quoted form of POSIX path of input
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "/usr/bin/emacs " & filepath
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

[image]

Save this anywhere you want, as an `.app` file. Now, you can right-click on any file, go to *Open With… » Other* and select your new app. You can also go to *Get Info* after right-clicking, and under *Open With…*, set your new emacs-app as a default for all files of this type.